# Struggling to define variable using variable previously defined

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core

new to tikz and am struggling to figure out how to define a variable using variables I have just defined. I think the problem in the code below is coming from the following section:

```
\def\vx{\asx-\sqx}
\def\vy{\asy-\sqy}
\def\magv{sqrt({\vx*\vx} + {\vy*\vy})}
\def\propx{\sqx + \vx/\magv+\winsetshock}
\def\propy{\sqy + \vy/\magv+\winsetshock}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
"Package pgf Error: no shape is known. 
...
\node at (\propx,\propy){\textbf{$p$}};"
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Also, any suggestions as to how to make this more applicable to other tikz newbies greatfully received...

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\axisoffset{0.1};
\def\labeloffset{.05};
\def\winsetshock{.1}
\def\sqx{.5}
\def\sqy{.5}
\def\asx{.7}
\def\asy{.9}
\def\vx{\asx-\sqx}
\def\vy{\asy-\sqy}
\def\magv{sqrt({\vx*\vx} + {\vy*\vy})}
\def\propx{\sqx + \vx/\magv+\winsetshock}
\def\propy{\sqy + \vy/\magv+\winsetshock}
\foreach \i in {0, \thexshift}{
  \foreach \j in {0}{  
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\i,\j)}]
      \draw[thick] (0, -\axisoffset) --  (1, -\axisoffset); 
      \draw[thick] (-\axisoffset,0) --  (-\axisoffset, 1); 
    \end{scope} 
  }
}
\def\laboffset{-.35};
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)}]
  \node at (.5, 1.25) {\textbf{Non-crisis}};    
  \draw[dotted] (\sqx,\sqy) circle [radius=\winsetshock];
  \draw[dashed] (.5,.9) --  (.7, .1);
  \node at (\sqx,\sqy) {\textbf{$SQ$}};
  \node at (\asx,\asy) {\textbf{$AS$}};
  \node at (\propx,\propy) {\textbf{$p$}};
\end{scope}
```

Comment: It starts with defining `\thexshift`. Also note that TeX doesn't parse math right away. So `\def`ining `\propx` won't work that way. If you can complete your document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` we can look at it together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calculations can be done by `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\vx{\asx-\sqx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\vy{\asy-\sqy}
\pgfmathsetmacro\magv{sqrt(\vx*\vx + \vy*\vy)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\propx{\sqx + \vx/\magv+\winsetshock}
\pgfmathsetmacro\propy{\sqy + \vy/\magv+\winsetshock}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a great answer and works just as described. Perfect.